# Call Private Class from Main. Both in Public Class

Tags: java, class, private, program-entry-point

My code looks like this:

```
public class Hello{

    private class Word{ 
        ... 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Word W = new Hello.Word();
    }
}
```

How can I call the class Word from main?

```
Word W = new Hello.Word();
```

seems not to be the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate non-static class inside another, from a static context.

Either make the inner class static:

```
 private static class Word{ 
    ... 
 }
```

(However, you wouldn't need the `Hello` part, just `Word W = new Word();` would do perfectly)

Or create an instance of the outer class, and then create an instance of the inner class using that. ([Sotirios suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18937264/1667004) this solution too, but with better details.)

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
Hello.Word word = new Hello().new Word();
```

Since `Word` is an inner class, you need an instance of the outer class to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

`Word` is inner class of `Hello`,i.e., without  existing of `Hello` class instance there no chance of `Word` class instance existence.
so you have to create an object `Hello` first and then `Word` object.
Try this

```
    Hello.Word W =  new Hello(). new Word();
```